# El Autoloader no esta funcionando en mi Servidor / Hosting pero si en computadora local

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto con PHP, y para poder lograr que otras personas vayan viendo avances de la pagina, publique esto en un hosting (ByetHost). Al inicio todo bien porque unicamente lo que hice fue solo montar un diseño.

Ahora bien, estoy dando mis primeros pasos con el tema de la autenticación, asi que comence por crear un controlador de prueba y otro script que simplemente valida si el controllador existe o no para redireccionarte. Hice esto en mi computadora primero, lo cual funciono como se esperaba, pero a la hora de publicarlo al servidor por alguna extraña razón, las clases no las esta encontrando.

Cai en cuenta que ni siquiera las clases se estaban cargando luego de depurar y realizar pruebas con la funcion **class_exists**.

```
function app_autoloader($class){
$file = $class.'.php';
if(file_exists($file)){
    require_once $file;
}
}

spl_autoload_register("app_autoloader");
```

No quiero pensar que por ser un hosting gratuito te limiten a realizar estas practicas.

Si es el caso tal de que mi autoloader no es el indicado (por la manera que se esta cargando los archivos), me gustaria saber cual seria la manera correcta de cargar las clases para que funcionen en ambos lados (tanto en mi computadora como en el servidor)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Descubri que el autoloader ni siquiera se esta ejecutando.

Hice una prueba escribiendo un echo dentro de la funcion para ver si me imprime las direcciones de las clases (en mi computadora y en el servidor), y pude notar que en mi computadora si se llegan a imprimir, mas en el servidor no.

```
function app_autoloader($class){
    $file = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class).'.php';
    echo $file.'<br/>';
    if(is_readable($file)){
        require_once $file;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("app_autoloader");
```

Asi que como conclusión, en mi hosting ni siquiera se llega a cargar el autoloader por algun motivo.

```
require_once  'autoload.php';
```

Intente con concatenar esta variable global pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

```
require_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
```

Comment: Tienes posibilidad de comparar el phpinfo para ver si están configurados diferente?

Comment: intenta cambiando `file_exists()` por `is_readable()` que verifica si el archivo existe y tambien si es legible . lo otro seria verificar el directory separator. ya que para windows es `\\`` y para linux es `/`

Comment: Hice un cambio en mi loader para que sea compatible para linux y windows usando str_replace y DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, pero continuaba sin funcionar.... despues de maliciar me di cuenta que por alguna razon no esta incluyendo el autoloader donde yo quiero ( require_once  'autoload.php'; ). @Bryro

Comment: Hice una ultima prueba en mi computadora y en el servidor. Le coloque un echo para que me vaya imprimiendo las rutas de todas las clases, y efectivamente, en mi computadora si se llegaron a imprimir pero en el servidor no... la estructura es exactamente igual en ambos lados. No me parece normal esto.

Comment: puede ser permisos intenta dandole el el cpanel, busca algo que diga permisos